# How could I specify a function that can accept any type exclude one type in typed/racket?

Tags: scheme, racket, typed-racket

I mean, just like annotate a function as

`(: function (-> (Not String) String))`

I know this doesn't work, is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: What makes a string special that it cannot work with your function but it would somehow work with every other data type, including ones a user may not have even defined yet?

Comment: This is just an example...actually I may use a function like
`(define-type Keywords (U "int" "float" ...)) (: function (-> (∩ String (Not Keywords)) String)`

Comment: It might be easier to define the typed function as accepting `any` and then handle *"not string"* with an untyped contract. Perhaps `flat-contract-with-reason` internally https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/data-structure-contracts.html. From a user perspective, it would be difficult to tell the difference.

Comment: @benrudgers Yes, that's exactly what I do now. Just wondering if there is a way to implement this using the type system :P

Comment: As far as I know, this is not supported with the current type system

Comment: I'm curious about the use case. It seems like there might be a leaky abstraction since a sequence of bytes would pass because Racket's `string` type is not a pure implementation of the computational concept of strings. The `string` type is conceived in the context of texts to be interpreted by humans. However, the program is free to interpret anything as this type of string, for example integers.